# How to connect to an Azure SQL DB in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, powerbi, azure-sql-database

I have been struggling to connect to my Azure SQL DB from Power BI and SSMS.

I've configured the firewall settings for the server to include my client IP address, enabled 'Azure services and resources' and am able to query my database with both Azure AD and username and password.

I've read that I should troubleshoot by running ping, telnet and tracert and it's failing to reach the server. I'm not sure of the next steps that I should take though.

My power BI error:

[image]

My cmd output:

[image]

My ssms output:

[image]

Is there something basic that I am missing? All of the tutorials I've read and watched seem to connect first time without an issue. I assume this is straightforward enough but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Any help and advice is much appreciated :)

SSMS 17.2 version 14.0.17177.0

Comment: The error you're getting in SSMS has two causes generally. A) You have the wrong connection string. B) Your IP address doesn't have access. The connection string for SSMS should be the same for AD. If you can connect from the one, you should be able to connect from the other. What version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: SSMS 17.2 version 14.0.17177.0

Comment: Yeah I can connect to the database with that connection string in a logic app. I read somewhere that the port that allows external clients to connect is closed by default. I think it's the latter.

Comment: Then I'm back to A or B as the root cause. There's no special tricks or secret sauce. Get the connection string, xxx.database.windows.net, set the firewall to the right IP address, login and password. You're good to go. Are you running SSMS from inside a VM or a container or something that could lead to it having a different IP address?

Comment: So, from the same client, you can connect using Azure Data Studio? SSMS should just work. Something is up. I'm not sure what.

Comment: No VM or anything like that. Not sure about Azure Data Studio but I can login through the logic app and query using the query editor on the database resource. How can I check I have entered the correct IP address? I've added the client IP which is prompted in the firewall settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have successfully configured your azure SQL to accept traffic from your IP then the issue seems to be with your local firewall blocking outbound connections

Things I would try:

- From Azure Portal connect to your database and try to use the query editor online to see if you are able to connect
- Use https://www.whatismyip.com/ to verify your public IP matches the one that's on the Azure SQL configuration (your error doesn't indicate that the server blocked the connection but worth double checking anyway)
- Lastly is to check from the local machine you are connecting that the "outbound" connection on port 1433 are not blocked. If you are connecting FROM an azure VM then you need to configure the NSG to allow outbound connection. If you are connecting from a local machine then you need to check if there's a local firewall or a VPN that's blocking this connection

From your description and the steps you described the last option above seems like the most likely scenario

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I think you are correct - it's a firewall issue that is blocking it

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it? If you explain a bit more your current network between your machine and azure we may be able to help more. If you're connecting from a corporate network or via a vpn it may be where your block is. Not uncommon for networks to disallow outgoing 1433 unless explicitly allowed

Comment: Haven't managed to progress any further as of yet. No VPN, I'm using the free £40 a month subscription as part of my vs subscription. I spoke to a colleague of mine and he has had a similar issue regarding the firewalls - I think you're right, the firewall settings need to be approved by the IT admins. I'll get back once i hear something from them, thank you!

Comment: good to hear @Greg. Let me know if you get stuck and will be happy to help further if needed

Comment: I was just thinking, it might be worth while setting up a VM in Azure and connecting that way, although this might only be a temp solution as I've heard it can get expensive!

Comment: You could definitely try that to confirm it's a local block issue. You'll need to setup the NSG for the VM to allow that traffic. I'd go with a very basic VM which will just confirm the above assumption

Comment: Didn't work either- had the same firewall issue. I think I'll just develop on my personal machine instead. Thanks for your help man!